# Is CTime nullable?

Tags: winapi, mfc, null, nullable, ctime

In a MFC application I like to map SQL date values (`CDBVariant`) to MFC `CTime`. Because the database entries can be NULL (value does not exist), I wonder if `CTime` is nullable. The [remark in the MFC documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29btb3sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `CTime::Format` makes me thinking, it should be possible:

> If the status of this CTime object is null, the return value is an empty string.

- But how to set this status, is it even possible?
- If it isn't possible, I guess `boost::optional<CTime>` would be a good alternative?

Comment: The default ctor creates an uninitialized CTime, so you could assign from that.

Comment: @roger_rowland: I tried `CTime tmp` and `CTime tmp = CTime()`. In both cases `Format` returns `01.01.1970' (a valid date), and not an empty string as the documentation says.

Comment: That's a pain - I guess the next best thing is to wrap a CTime and a bool in a struct and use that instead. Use the bool to flag non-null CTime. Anyone have other ideas?

Comment: +1 for `boost::optional`. It's the most "idiomatic" solution.

Comment: Use COleDateTime. it has a "status" attribute. One of the values is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTime is just a wrapper for a `__time64_t`. When you call format it does this:

```
inline CString CTime::Format(_In_z_ LPCTSTR pFormat) const
{
    if(pFormat == NULL)
    {
        return pFormat;
    }

    TCHAR szBuffer[maxTimeBufferSize];
    struct tm ptmTemp;

    if (_localtime64_s(&ptmTemp, &m_time) != 0)
    {
        AtlThrow(E_INVALIDARG);
    }

    if (!_tcsftime(szBuffer, maxTimeBufferSize, pFormat, &ptmTemp))
    {
        szBuffer[0] = '\0';
    }
    return szBuffer;
}
```

So the system function you want to look at is `_tcsftime`. And this is where I think the documentation is not very accurate. If the `_localtime64_s` fails you'll get an exception so a 'null' time can't really be passed to `_tcsftime`. You'll only get a NULL if `_tcsftime` fails but that won't be because of a 'null' time.

So, in short, use something like you suggest of `boost::optional` to represent null.

Comment: Thanks for the insight into MFC and your analysis. I'm going with `boost::optional`, first time I used it and it works well.